# viewer.getPlugin(PhotoSphereViewer.MarkersPlugin) return null

Tags: javascript, jquery, photosphereviewer

I use [PhotosphereViewer](https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/)  for displaying panorama image.

I use the following code for initializing the viewer successfully -

```
var viewer = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
            panorama: '/images/myimage.jpg',
            container: 'stage',
            loadingImg: 'https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/assets/photosphere-logo.gif',
            caption: 'Parc national du Mercantour <b>&copy; Damien Sorel</b>',
            defaultLat: 0.3,

            plugins: [
                [PhotoSphereViewer.MarkersPlugin, {
                    // list of markers
                    markers: [
                    ]
                }]
            ]
        });
```

After initializing the viewer I use the following command to get a reference to the MarkersPlugin -

```
var markersPlugin = viewer.getPlugin(PhotoSphereViewer.MarkersPlugin);
```

Any idea why `markersPlugin` is always null ?

Comment: How many scripts you have loaded in your HTML? Can we see the list of CSS and JS files related to this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `markers.js` file in your html

Like

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/photo-sphere-viewer@4/dist/plugins/markers.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add something to the markers, as in the example
https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/plugins/plugin-markers.html#usage

Comment: Tried it with a coded marker..., still I get null in markersPlugin.

Comment: It's hard to say what happened. It would be great if you reproduce it at codesnadbox